# How do you make a thread idle in Java when using a thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client, threadpool

I'm working on a server/client solution which creates a new server-thread for each client that is connected (adds it to a thread pool). The server-thread waits for a message from the associated client by calling `readLine()` on the clients sockets input stream. If I set the thread pool to 1 and connect a second client it won't get executed by the thread pool until the first thread is shut down. I was under the impression that a thread pool would automatically idle a thread if it was just waiting on readLine() but I guess that is not the case. How would I go about creating such a program?

This is the server loop which creates new server-threads connected to a client:

```
private final static Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_CLIENTS);

while (true) {
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    executor.execute(new ChatServer(clientSocket, allClients));
}
```

And the run-method works like this:

```
socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())

while(true) {
    inputLine = socketReader.readLine();
    //then send input line to all clients
}
```

As said if the FixedThreadPool is already running `MAX_CLIENTS` no new clients will get executed.

Comment: So, you want to have one thread processing multiple clients, right?

Comment: No, in my first code snippet I'm creating one new thread for every client that connects to the socket. So that every client has one server-thread each which processes its messages and also sends that message to all other clients (it's a chat program).

Comment: Well, in that case you should increase the number of threads in the thread pool. You can not just 'reuse' a thread wich is waiting for something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Your current design You are going to run out of threads as the number of the the clients goes up. If Your thread pool is size of 20 threads, You cant handle 21 clients simultaneously. Because socket operations are blocking operations.(and Your ChatServer class will keep the executing thread busy with while(true) loop)

You should check [AsynchronousSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html) and [AsynchronousServerSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html) classes which support async IO operations. To be able to use these classes You have to change most of Your client server communication logic.

Check out the following links for details and example usage of these classess.

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2853780/socket-programming-for-scalable-systems.html

https://webtide.com/on-jdk-7-asynchronous-io/